# how to init multi dynamic fetch requests in one view?

Tags: swiftui, core-data, dynamic, fetchrequest

One view needs multi dynamic fetchresults, so I write down the following code:

```
 @FetchRequest var dreamsForTheUser: FetchedResults<Dream>
    
    @FetchRequest var actionsForTheUser: FetchedResults<Action>
    
    @FetchRequest var actions: FetchedResults<Action>

    init(filterForTheUser: String, filter: String) {
        _dreamsForTheUser = FetchRequest<Dream>(sortDescriptors: [],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "dreamID BEGINSWITH %@", filterForTheUser))
        
        _actionsForTheUser = FetchRequest<Action>(sortDescriptors: [],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "actionID BEGINSWITH %@", filterForTheUser))
        
        _actions = FetchRequest<Action>(sortDescriptors: [],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "actionID == %@", filter))
    }
```

And I let the view show in another view with the following code:

```
 .sheet(isPresented: $editCurrentAction,content: {
            EditActionView(filterForTheUser: (userViewModel.userID ?? ""), filter: (action.actionID ?? ""))
        })
```

But the fetch results are wrong. It seems that the three fetchrequests use the same filter.  I think there are something wrong in the code about .init.  Could you help to check it? Really thanks.

Could you help to check the codes and point out the error?

Comment: Is actionID and dreamID the same thing?  And are they the same as userID?

Comment: No, they are not the same. In fact, I generate actionID by userID + “Action” + UUID().uuidString and generate dreamID by userID + “dream” + UUID().uuidString. I print them and found they are really unique. I get one action by actions.first. Since I set the filter as the actionID, the fetch result actions should contain only one object. So I should get the action object by actions.first. But the fact is that actions contain all actions of the user. So I think there should be sth wrong in init.

Comment: So it’s only the `actions` request that is wrong? But I don’t get that request at all, if you already have the action object then why do you need to fetch it? Why not pass the object to the view?

Comment: Yes, only actions fetch result is wrong. I want to get only one action by the actionID. But in fact, actions contains all actions of the user. I have set the filter for actions as the actionID. so actions should contain only one object. But it contains all the actions objects. That's really strange. It seems it hasn't used the correct filter. Now I have to filter the action by action = actionsForTheUser.first(where: {$0.actionID == actionViewModel.actionID})!. It works. I can get the correct action object. But I think the method is risky and isn't elegant because I use the force wrap.

Comment: You could try and remove `actions` as a FetchRequest in the view and instead use an NSFetchRequest that you execute in the view model instead. It's probably overkill to use a `@FetchRequest` to fetch a single object.

Comment: Hi, Joakim,  Really thanks for your suggestion. I want to try it but I search the internet and haven't found how to implement dynamic fetch with NSFetchRequest. Could you help to give some examples about it? I follow the guide from the link:https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui to implement dynamic fetch. But it hasn't mentioned how to implement it with NSFetchRequest.